# How can I get my mac terminal to color code my bash script?

Tags: macos, bash

So I am just wondering if it is possible make my mac display my bash script in color to make it easier to see minor mistakes and what not. Like in java

```
scan.nextInt();
```

Eclipse (a program to write code) will make the Int red. That is what I want pretty much. Just to make it easier to see my code. I don't even know if this is possible, so thanks for all who are willing to give advice.

Some other info : I have a MacBook with version 10.8.5

Comment: Which program are you looking at your bash script with?

Comment: Terminal emulators can't be expected to do syntax highlighting. Editors do that.

Comment: @pamphlet i am using the mac terminal

Comment: @larsmans what would be a good editor then?

Comment: @pamphlet is asking *what program* you're using.  The terminal can't read a file directly.

Comment: @Lifetake And what. Typing it in to the console?

Comment: @Lifetake: depends on your liking. I'm quite content with Vim, but the next guy will recommend Emacs.

Comment: As @larsmans points out, you need an _editor_, like _vim_ or _emacs_. (I recommend vim, but that's just a preference). Then you can configure it for _syntax highlighting_. There's plenty of info here on SO and online for both / either.

Comment: @larsmans ok thanks this will probably help. I was just trying to figure out if i could do this without getting a editor.

Comment: @pamphlet I am using terminal macs default program. I am usually using this and then moving it to a server which will color out the script, but I would much rather not have to work on the server all the time.

Comment: @Lifetake: what, in your opinion, is the "default program" for the Mac terminal emulator?

Comment: What he might be asking for is command line syntax highlighting like what is offered by the fish shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible in bash (mac default shell). You could use either [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) or zsh (my personal choice) with [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting).

If you opt for zsh I strongly recommend the [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) framework.

Comment: FYI: `tcsh` _was_ the default shell for OS X 10.0 thru 10.2 according to [old support docs](https://support.apple.com/kb/TA27005?viewlocale=en_US). `bash` is the default for 10.3 and up. OP is using 10.8, so he's most likely got `bash`

Answer (score 1):

Do you know vi? Install [MacVIM](https://github.com/b4winckler/macvim). MacVIM has built in Syntax highlighting. By the way, so does the `vim` command already on the Mac. Most likely, you need to setup your `.vimrc` file to turn on syntax highlighting for you.

Not too sure where I got this from, but this is a `.vimrc` file that turns on syntax highlighting for you:

```
" An example for a vimrc file.
"
" Maintainer:       Bram Moolenaar <Bram@vim.org>
" Last change:      2002 Sep 19
"
" To use it, copy it to
"     for Unix and OS/2:  ~/.vimrc
"         for Amiga:  s:.vimrc
"  for MS-DOS and Win32:  $VIM\_vimrc
"       for OpenVMS:  sys$login:.vimrc

" When started as "evim", evim.vim will already have done these settings.
if v:progname =~? "evim"
  finish
endif

" Use Vim settings, rather then Vi settings (much better!).
" This must be first, because it changes other options as a side effect.
set nocompatible

" allow backspacing over everything in insert mode
set backspace=indent,eol,start

if has("vms")
  set nobackup              " do not keep a backup file, use versions instead
else
  set backup                " keep a backup file
endif
set history=50              " keep 50 lines of command line history
set ruler           " show the cursor position all the time
set showcmd         " display incomplete commands
set incsearch               " do incremental searching

" For Win32 GUI: remove 't' flag from 'guioptions': no tearoff menu entries
" let &guioptions = substitute(&guioptions, "t", "", "g")

" Don't use Ex mode, use Q for formatting
map Q gq

" This is an alternative that also works in block mode, but the deleted
" text is lost and it only works for putting the current register.
"vnoremap p "_dp

" Switch syntax highlighting on, when the terminal has colors
" Also switch on highlighting the last used search pattern.
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
  syntax on
   set hlsearch
endif

" Only do this part when compiled with support for autocommands.
if has("autocmd")

  " Enable file type detection.
  " Use the default filetype settings, so that mail gets 'tw' set to 72,
  " 'cindent' is on in C files, etc.
  " Also load indent files, to automatically do language-dependent indenting.
  filetype plugin indent on

  " Put these in an autocmd group, so that we can delete them easily.
  augroup vimrcEx
  au!

  " For all text files set 'textwidth' to 78 characters.
  autocmd FileType text setlocal textwidth=78

  " When editing a file, always jump to the last known cursor position.
  " Don't do it when the position is invalid or when inside an event handler
  " (happens when dropping a file on gvim).
  autocmd BufReadPost *
    \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \   exe "normal g`\"" |
    \ endif

  augroup END

else

  set autoindent            " always set autoindenting on

endif " has("autocmd")
syntax on
set ai showmode showmatch report=1 sw=4 showcmd textmode ruler smartindent nobackup nohlsearch ff=unix diffopt+=iwhite
```

Answer (score 0):

Install [pygmentize](http://pygments.org/docs/cmdline/) `sudo easy_install Pygments` and then run `pygmentize script.sh`:

[image]

More examples:

```
pygmentize -l sh ~/.bashrc
pygmentize -L # list lexers, formatters, filters, and styles
pygmentize -H formatter terminal # help for the terminal formatter
pygmentize -f html -O full,style=emacs -o out.html file.rb
for f in **/*.rb;do printf "%-$COLUMNS"s $f|tr ' ' -;pygmentize $f;done
```